# How to resolve remote desktop error 0x204 in MS remote desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a macbook pro 13 running Mojave. I installed MS Remote Desktop and could access a Jetson Nano connected through a USB cable no problem.

Then suddenly I cannot connect anymore and I got the 0x204 error.

> We couldn't connect to the remote PC. Make sure the PC is turned on
>   and connected to the network. and that remote access is enabled

I have checked and the Jetson is connected and running. I could remote access to it through other means. (using the screen command from the terminal)

Apparently this is a common occurrence with ms remote desktop

How can I resolve this problem with MS Remote desktop?

Comment: Did you try restarting the RDP client and or your Mac?

Comment: SEe https://superuser.com/questions/1178706/the-connection-was-denied-because-the-user-account-is-not-authorized/1553243#1553243